# Showing $f(t)=\text{Tr}[A(I-A)^{2t}]\approx\frac{\sqrt{\pi/2}\,\text{erfc}(\sqrt{2t}\,/d)}{2\sqrt{t}}$, where $A=\text{diag}(1,1/4,1/9,\ldots,1/d^2)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose $h=\left(1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{9},\ldots,\frac{1}{d^2}\right)$ and $A=\operatorname{diag}(h)$

What's the easiest way of deriving the following expression in terms of [Erf](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) function?

$$f(t)=\operatorname{Tr}\left[A(I-A)^{2t}\right] \approx \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}}{d}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}} $$

The following tests goodness of fit against true values of $f(t)$ for fixed $d$ or fixed $t$

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-erfc-formula.nb)

Motivation: $f(t)$ gives loss after $t$ steps of gradient descent minimizing $y=x_1^2+\frac{1}{4}x_2^2+\frac{1}{9}x_3^2 + \ldots + \frac{1}{d^2}x_d^2$

Comment: Is $t\to \infty$ or $d\to\infty$

Comment: @Youem I believe this formula captures both regimes independently, in addition to the third regime where $t=C d^2$ and $d\to \infty$

Comment: When you fix $t$ and let $d$ go to $\infty$ the two terms do not converges to the same limit

Comment: @Youem The erfc formula has two different limiting behaviors depending on how fast $d$ grows relative to $t$: $\frac{d e^{-\frac{2 t}{d^2}}}{4 t}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \sqrt{t}}$

Comment: Could you please add the definition of $\text{erfc}$ function because with the definition that i know what you said does not seem correct

Comment: @Youem I was using erfc=1-erf. I think Erf is well known and just has 1 definition, hence redid all formulas with erf and rechecked asymptotics for new formula in [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-erfc-formula.nb)

Comment: @Youem I did a spot-check with $t=10$ and $d=\infty$, and get $0.19..$ both using exact sum and $\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{2 \sqrt{t}}$ formula, here's the [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REZ1Z.png) for $t$ up to $100$

Comment: Yes the behaviour is correct. I proved it in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $$\forall x\in \mathbb R,\; 1 + x \le e^x$$

Now for all $y\in \mathbb R$, $1 + y^2 \le e^{y^2}$ and $1 \le e^{y^2}$ this proves that $$1 + y^2 + 2y \le (1 + 2y)e^{y^2}$$ So, $$(1+y)^2 \le (1+2y)e^{y^2}$$ and $$e^{-y^2} \le \frac{1 + 2y}{(1+y)^2} = 1 - \left(\frac{y}{1 + y}\right)^2$$

So, $$\forall y\in \mathbb R,\; e^{-y^2} \le 1 - \left(\frac{y}{1 + y}\right)^2$$

Finally, for $n\in \mathbb N$,

\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n\right) &= \frac{n-1}n\frac1{n(n-1)}\\
&= \frac1{n^2} \le \frac1{n(n-1)}\\
&= \frac1{n-1} - \frac1n
\end{align}

This proves these three inequalities:

$$\forall x\in \mathbb R,\; 1 + x \le e^x$$ $$\forall y \in \mathbb R,\; e^{-y^2} \le 1 - \left(\frac{y}{1 + y}\right)^2$$ $$\forall n\in \mathbb N,\, n \ge 1 \;\; \left(1 - \frac1n\right) \left(\frac1{n-1} - \frac1n\right) \le \frac1{n^2} \le \frac1{n-1} - \frac1n$$

---

We have for all $t$, $d$,

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=2}^{d} \frac1{n^2} \left(1 - \frac1{n^2}\right)^{2t}$$

Using $x = -\frac1{n^2}$ and $y = \frac1{n-1}$, you will have:

$$e^{-\frac1{(n-1)^2}} \le 1 - \frac1{n^2} \le e^{-\frac1{n^2}}$$

Using the third inequality and summing:

$$\sum_{n=2}^d\left(1 - \frac1n\right)\left(\frac1{n-1} - \frac1n\right)e^{-\frac{2t}{(n-1)^2}} \le f(t) \le \sum_{n=2}^d\left(\frac1{n-1} - \frac1n\right)e^{-\frac{2t}{n^2}}$$

Using the fact that $u\to e^{-2tu^2}$ is non increasing in $(0, \infty)$ then,

$$\sum_{n=2}^{d} \int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} \left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du \le f(t) \le \sum_{n=2}^d\int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du$$

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^d\int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du &= \int_{\frac1d}^1 e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}\int_{\sqrt{2t}/d}^{\sqrt{2t}} e^{-s^2}\mathrm ds
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{d} \frac1n \int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du &\le \sum_{n=2}^{d} \int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} ue^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du \\
&= \int_{\frac1{d}}^{1} ue^{-2tu^2}\mathrm d u\\
&= \frac1{4t}\left(e^{-2t} - e^{-\frac{2t}{d^2}}\right)
\end{align}

---

Do you think that from these expressions you have the behaviour that you are looking for?

Comment: So as I understand, the key inequality is the following, which absorbs the $\pi$ factors. Will check tomorrow how tight it is...do you have a way to simplify the leftmost term? $$\sum_{n=2}^{d} \int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} \left(1-\frac1n\right)e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du \le f(t) \le \sum_{n=2}^d\int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du$$

Comment: Yes the left most term is the $\erf$

Comment: I meant the extra part, with $\frac{1}{n}$. We have the following. What simpler form of $v$? We have $$u - v \le f(t) \le u\\
u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}\int_{\sqrt{2t}/d}^{\sqrt{2t}} e^{-s^2}\mathrm ds\\v=\sum_{n=2}^{d} \int_{\frac1n}^{\frac1{n-1}} \left(\frac1n\right)e^{-2tu^2}\mathrm du$$

Comment: This part I bound it by something which is worse than the erf in the last inequality